# NodeJS routing -

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

#### **Summary:**

I call the code below once and everything is just fine the next time I call it I get the error below the code then I need to restart the server in order for it to work, but again, it works only once.

#### **NOTE:**

The reason I was using eventEmitter is because if I nest two db requests with mongoose it will do parent then its childs so I had to make sure first one is done in order to run the second one. but thats not the problem code works,  but only the first time I run it. Never had this problem before, I'm really curious whats going on

**Code:**

```
// loads people user has chatted with
router.get('/loadUserChats', function(req, res) {
    var hostID = req.query.id;
    let list = [];
    let readyToSend = true;

    // gets photos for each user in the 'list'
    eventEmitter.on('addPictureToObjects', function() {
        list.forEach(function(listItem, i) {
            User.findOne({_id: listItem.id}, 'photo', function(err, guest) {
                listItem.photo = guest.photo;
                // if this is the last one send json object back
                if (i+1 == list.length) {
                    res.json({list: list});
                }
            });
        });
    });

    // get the user
    User.findOne({_id: hostID}, function(err, user) {
        // checks if user has chatted at all
        if (user.chat) {
            // loops through the chat
            user.chat.forEach(function(chat) {
                var photoURL = "";
                console.log(chat.user);
                // push the chat info so later we can load messages
                // by its ID
                list.push({
                    id: chat.user.id,
                    name: chat.user.name
                });
            });
            // okay, now that we are done looping lets add photos
            // to each one of those so it looks better
            eventEmitter.emit('addPictureToObjects');
        }
    });
});
```

**ERROR:**

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
  at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
  at ServerResponse.header (/home/knox97/Documents/agro/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
  at ServerResponse.json (/home/knox97/Documents/agro/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:247:10)
  at /home/knox97/Documents/agro/routes/api.js:249:10
  at Query.<anonymous> (/home/knox97/Documents/agro/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3357:16)
  at /home/knox97/Documents/agro/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21
  at /home/knox97/Documents/agro/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I actually fixed the problem by rewriting the code and adding photo to chat list objects initialy so I dont have to add photos manualy, its faster and more clever solution, but I'm really curious why this didnt work, like or share this question so we can both find out, cheers!

Comment: You constantly adding an eventEmitter, IOW: each request is going to get another eventEmitter, so your next request will be going to 2 eventEmiiters,.. Personally I wound't do it the way you are.  But you can remove the eventEmmiter after you have finished with it.

Comment: Actually even better, if you are going to use eventEmiiter, use `once` instead of `on`.

Answer (score 0):

Pull your event emitter out of the route handler. Every time the route handler runs you're adding ***another*** event handler for `'addPictureToObjects'`. You do want to emit that event on every request but you don't want to register the event handler on every request, only once.

You're getting the error `"Can't set headers after they are sent."` because the first event handler runs, iterates all items in `list`, then calls `res.json` which sends the response back to the client. But since you registered multiple event handlers with each request, it runs that code twice (or three times, or four times, etc. depending on how many times you've hit that route and registered a new event handler each time). On subsequent runs of that code when it gets to `res.json` for a second time it errors out saying it can't modify the response anymore because it was already sent back to the client.

```
// gets photos for each user in the 'list'
eventEmitter.on('addPictureToObjects', function(list, res) {
  list.forEach(function(listItem, i) {
    User.findOne({_id: listItem.id}, 'photo', function(err, guest) { 
      listItem.photo = guest.photo;
      // if this is the last one send json object back
      if (i+1 == list.length) {
        res.json({list: list});
      }
    });
  });
});    

// loads people user has chatted with
router.get('/loadUserChats', function(req, res) {
  var hostID = req.query.id;
  let list = [];
  let readyToSend = true;

  // get the user
  User.findOne({_id: hostID}, function(err, user) {
    // checks if user has chatted at all
    if (user.chat) {
      // loops through the chat
      user.chat.forEach(function(chat) {
        var photoURL = "";
        console.log(chat.user);
        // push the chat info so later we can load messages
        // by its ID
        list.push({
          id: chat.user.id,
          name: chat.user.name
        });
      });
      // okay, now that we are done looping lets add photos
      // to each one of those so it looks better
      eventEmitter.emit('addPictureToObjects', list, res);
    }
  });
});
```

You could also just change `eventEmitter.on` to `eventEmitter.once` and that would fix your problem as well. `.once` registers the event handler but then deregisters it after it runs. However, it seems pointless in your code as it doesn't seem like there's a reason to register the handler and deregister it over and over with each request, so registering the event handler outside of your request handler seems like the ideal fix.

---

This wasn't your actual question, but you don't need the event emitter here. It's still doing the first db request, then in the callback for that request it's emitting the event to do the second one. It's still doing one request and then the other. The event emitter didn't change that. The following code is equivalent to the above:

```
// loads people user has chatted with
router.get('/loadUserChats', function(req, res) {
  var hostID = req.query.id;
  let list = [];
  let readyToSend = true;

  // get the user
  User.findOne({_id: hostID}, function(err, user) {
    // checks if user has chatted at all
    if (user.chat) {
      // loops through the chat
      user.chat.forEach(function(chat) {
        var photoURL = "";
        console.log(chat.user);
        // push the chat info so later we can load messages
        // by its ID
        list.push({
          id: chat.user.id,
          name: chat.user.name
        });
      });
      // okay, now that we are done looping lets add photos
      // to each one of those so it looks better
      list.forEach(function(listItem, i) {
        User.findOne({_id: listItem.id}, 'photo', function(err, guest) { 
          listItem.photo = guest.photo;
          // if this is the last one send json object back
          if (i+1 == list.length) {
            res.json({list: list});
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```